# jquery selector char and number regex

Tags: jquery, css, regex, selector

I need to select all the id like this :

r1
r2
r3 
etc.
and no the other id like helloWorld

I try to use the css selector with jQuery but I don't understand how.
I trying $('#r[0-9]') but don't work.

Ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID selector (`#`) only works with a specific ID.  You want to use the attribute selector.

```
$("[id^=r]")
```